# Какой паттерн нужно пременить?

Tags: php

В общем есть 4 поля нужно их сортировать по убыванию и по возрастанию.
и есть Класс для выполнения запроса к базе.

Какой паттерн применить. Подскажите?

класс достает из базы.

```
class Scroll extends Entyty
{

    public function show($Wquery)
    {
        $db = DB::getInstance();
        $query="SELECT `name`, `seurname`,`group`,`balls` FROM users"."$Wquery";
        $result = $db->query($query);
        if (!$result) {
            die($db->error);
        }
        $json = [];
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $json[] = [$row['name'],$row['seurname'],$row['group'],$row['balls']];
        }
        return $json;
    }
}
```

Класс сортирует по `DESC`

```
class DESK
{
    public $name;
    public $group;
    public $seurname;
    public $balls;

    public function DESKname(){
       return $this->name='ORDER BY name DESC';
    }

    public function DESKgroup(){
       return $this->group='ORDER BY group DESC';
    }

    public function DESKseurname(){
       return $this->seurname='ORDER BY seurname DESC';
    }

    public function DESKballs(){
       return $this->balls='ORDER BY balls DESC';
    }

}
```

Класс сортирует по `ASC`

```
class ASK
{
    public $name;
    public $group;
    public $seurname;
    public $balls;

     public function ASCname(){
        return  $this->name='ORDER BY name ASC';
     }

    public function ASCgroup(){
        return  $this->group='ORDER BY group ASC';
    }

    public function ASCseurname(){
        return  $this->seurname='ORDER BY seurname ASC';
    }

    public function ASCballs(){
        return $this->balls='ORDER BY balls ASC';
    }    
}
```

Вопрос Как правильно впихнуть в метод `show()` нужный метод из классов `ASC` && `DESK`

Или как бы было правильно сделать?
Зарание благодарю.

Comment: вы и к самым элементарным задачам пытаетесь что то применить? суть проблемы изложите с кодом, иначе не ясно вообще о чем речь

Comment: @ tean Добавил КОТА

Comment: и кому сдались эти одноразовые классы? вы так увлеклись ООП кодом, что не понимаете смысл его применения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте класс `Select` у которого будут реализованы всё эти методы, из классов `ASC`, `DESC`

при создание запроса, используйте что-то вроде

```
$select = new Select();
$select->from('table')->orderBy('column', 'DESC');
```

У большинство фрейворков это уже реализовано, можете посмотреть как это сделано у Zend-да

**UPDATE**
Ваш код мог бы выглядеть так

Класс `Select`

```
class Select {

    protected $_table = null;
    protected $_colums = [];
    protected $_order = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function from($table, $columns = [])
    {
        $this->_table = $table;

        if (!empty($columns)) {
            $this->_colums = $columns;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function orderBy($column, $type)
    {
        $this->_order[$column] = $column . ' ' . $type;
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        // Собираем SQL


        $sql = 'SELECT ';
        if (! empty($this->_colums)) {
            $sql .= implode(', ', $this->_colums);
        } else {
            $sql .= '*';
        }

        if (is_null($this->_table)) {
            throw new Exception('Таблица не определена');
        }

        $sql .= ' FROM ' . $this->_table;

        if (!empty($this->_order)) {
            $sql .= ' ORDER BY ' . implode(', ', $this->_order);
        }

        return $sql;
    }

}
```

Использование

```
class Scroll extends Entyty
{

    public function show($Wquery)
    {
        $db = DB::getInstance();
        $select = new Select();
        $select->from('users', ['name', 'seurname', 'group', 'balls'])
            ->orderBy('name', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('surname', 'ASC');

        $result = $db->query($select->__toString());
        if (!$result) {
            die($db->error);
        }
        $json = [];
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $json[] = [$row['name'],$row['seurname'],$row['group'],$row['balls']];
        }
        return $json;
    }
}
```

Comment: from(' table') здесь вот такой код "SELECT `name`, `seurname`,`group`,`balls` FROM users"

Comment: Подскажи мне нужно для понимания больше объяснения а то я не врубаюсь.

Comment: А куда делся show() там где я достаю все поля?? из базы

Comment: Я новичек нужен пример .. Я так не пойму

Comment: @ДимаПерильман просмотрите, что-то вроде этого, класс не является конечным, а представлен для демонстрации мысли

Comment: @ Farkhod Daniyarov Прививет еще раз) В общем я посмотрел на твой код, и действительно сделал все по другому. Чуть проще. Применив паттер Строитель. Спасибо за магический метод tostring))